# Match coordinates in dataset with nearest neighbor more efficiently - and retain names?

Tags: r

I'm trying to match businesses with the nearest business within the same dataset. The dataset consists of the business name, coordinates, and star rating (out of 5). There is a row for every business, per quarter, per year (about 5 years). While I've figured this out for simply the *nearest* business, I need to do this ~100 more times based on different criteria. (Splitting into different quarters for each year, matching neighbors with same ratings, etc).

Right now all I can think of doing is splitting the dataset to include only the businesses I need based on the criteria and then matching like that — but doing it 100 times, and then rejoining the data, sounds...like a terrible idea. I'm not too experienced with spatial stuff in R, so if anyone has any ideas or help that would be amazing.

Similarly, for the existing code I have (below), this provides me with the ID # of the nearest neighbor, but not the name. Is there a way to match neighbors while retaining other columns other than simply the ID #?

The code I already have is below. I'm using

```
library(RANN)
sp.data <- data
coordinates(sp.data) <- ~lon+lat
sf.data <- st_as_sf(sp.data)
dist_m <- st_distance(sf.data, sf.data)
index <- apply(dist_m, 1, order)
index <- index[2:nrow(index), ]
index <- index[1, ]
index2 <- as.data.frame(index)
index2 <- data.frame(t(index2))
```

This then provides me with the ID# of the nearest neighbor. As you can see, running this over and over again with different data (split from the original data based on rating criteria and quarter, etc) isn't very efficient. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think your logic of including only businesses you need, *calculating the `dist` for all of them*, and then rejoining the data is likely your best bet. If you can make this question at all reproducible, it's more likely you'll get a response, even if you just make just a half-dozen businesses with fake quarter/year data. If your data has businesses that are not in all quarters/years, make sure the sample has a gap or two, as well.

Comment: @r2evans - Thank you - I'm not super super experienced with R so it's good to hear that my initial idea to just run through it individually made sense (I thought there may be something obvious I'm overlooking).